# PHP Regex find text between custom added HTML Tags

Tags: php, regex

I have he following scenario:

Got an **HTML template** file that will be used for `mailing`.

**Here is a reduced example:**

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td>Heading 1</td>
<td>heading 2</td>
</tr>
<PRODUCT_LIST>
<tr>
<td>Value 1</td>
<td>Value 2</td>
</tr>
</PRODUCT_LIST>
</table>
```

All I need to do is to get the HTML code inside `<PRODUCT_LIST>` and then repeat that code as many times as products I have on an array.

**What would be the right PHP Regex code for getting/replacing this List?**

Thanks!

Comment: Technically, that's not an HTML tag; that's an XHTML tag. Or, rather, it's an XML tag in an XHTML document that also uses another custom namespace. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/normative.html#well-formed

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Assuming `<PRODUCT_LIST>` tags will never be nested**

```
preg_match_all('/<PRODUCT_LIST>(.*?)<\/PRODUCT_LIST>/s', $html, $matches);

//HTML array in $matches[1]
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: <PRODUCT_LIST> tags will never be nested, but using this code i get two empty matches...
array(2) {
  [0]=>  array(0) {}
  [1]=>  array(0) {}
}

Comment: Using the HTML snippet you pasted, I get an array with only one element containing the HTML inside the PRODUCT_LIST tags. Perhaps you should post a more complete HTML sample.

Answer (score 12):

Use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It's easy to understand and use .

```
$html = str_get_html($content);
$el = $html->find('PRODUCT_LIST', 0);
$innertext = $el->innertext;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this function. It will return all found values as an array.

```
<?php
function get_all_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $result = array();
    $string = " ".$string;
    $offset = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        $ini = strpos($string,$start,$offset);
        if ($ini == 0)
            break;
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        $result[] = substr($string,$ini,$len);
        $offset = $ini+$len;
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = get_all_string_between($input_string, '<PRODUCT_LIST>', '</PRODUCT_LIST>');
```

Comment: HTML is not regular.  Something like this will work for the simple example provided, but it won't work for something with nested tags (`<foo><PRODUCT_LIST><bar><PRODUCT_LIST><baz /></PRODUCT_LIST></bar><buz/></PRODUCT_LIST></foo>`).  So it's not a good generic solution (no -1 since it does fit the needs of the example provided)...  The better and more generic solution would be to use a DOM parser (SimpleXML, DomDocument, SimpleHtmlDom, etc)...

Comment: @ircmaxell, yes I agree. But as he is specifying his **own** tags, it may be regular. Just another way to solve it.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done or it's "bad" to do (otherwise I would have `-1`)...  I'm just saying it's not a generic solution.  It's perfectly OK as long as the problem scope fits within the limitations of the solution.  I was just pointing out the limitations (so that the problem scope can be better assessed)...

Comment: @ircmaxell, Yes I agree fully with you.

Answer (score 2):

as above is ok but with performance is really horrible
If You can use PHP 5 you can use DOM object like this :

```
     <?php
      function getTextBetweenTags($tag, $html, $strict=0)
    {
     /*** a new dom object ***/
    $dom = new domDocument;

    /*** load the html into the object ***/
    if($strict==1)
    {
        $dom->loadXML($html);
    }
    else
    {
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
    }

    /*** discard white space ***/
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    /*** the tag by its tag name ***/
    $content = $dom->getElementsByTagname($tag);

    /*** the array to return ***/
    $out = array();
    foreach ($content as $item)
    {
        /*** add node value to the out array ***/
        $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
    }
    /*** return the results ***/
    return $out;
}
?>
```

and after adding this function You can just use it as:

```
$content = getTextBetweenTags('PRODUCT_LIST', $your_html);

foreach( $content as $item )
{
    echo $item.'<br />';
}
?>
```

yep, i just learn this today. dont use preg for html with php5

Answer (score 0):

try this `regular expression` in `preg match all function`

```
<PRODUCT_LIST>(.*?)<\/PRODUCT_LIST>
```