# How to use substring in php when data stored in html format in mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, substring, substr

Text is stored in HTML format paragraph tags.

Field Name:descr

Stored data:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="campusInfoNamesake">
<p>If someone had said to me ten years ago that autism and the therapeutic benefits of gardening will become your life, I wouldn&rsquo;t have believed them.</p>

<p>Although it&rsquo;s still very early days, things are starting to take shape on my smallholding in Ceredigion, West Wales.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above structure only datas stored in table see mysql table image bellow:

[image]

I need to retrive only 100 string in the body tag..
I used this code: **`<?php echo substr($row01[descr], 100); ?>`**
but i can't get the result when using this code.
Please help me.

Comment: $row01[descr] check this one it has data or not

Answer (score 0):

you need to use regex to retrieve everything between your `<body>`-Tags first, then you are able to cut the string you need.

```
preg_match_all('/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/s', $row01['desc'], $matches);

//HTML array in $matches[1]
print_r(substr($matches[1],100));
```

See regex here: [PHP Regex find text between custom added HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602251/php-regex-find-text-between-custom-added-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put myself in your shoes and make several assumptions about how best to prepare this text.  Let me know if I'm going to wrong way here...

Input:

```
$row01['descr']='<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="campusInfoNamesake">
<p>If someone had said to me ten years ago that autism and the therapeutic benefits of gardening will become your life, I wouldn&rsquo;t have believed them.</p>

<p>Although it&rsquo;s still very early days, things are starting to take shape on my smallholding in Ceredigion, West Wales.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>';
```

Method ([preg_match pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/1avCTA/1)) ([php demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/349ac59b7bbb03e67081455bc82d005c904db981)):

```
$body_text=preg_match('/<body>\s\K.+(?=<\/body)/s',$row01['descr'],$out)?$out[0]:'';  // extract body text
$tagless_text=strip_tags($body_text);                     // remove tags from body text
$decoded_text=html_entity_decode($tagless_text);          // decode entities like: &rsquo;
$pattern=['/[\n\r ]+/','/^ +| +$/'];                             
$replace=[' ',''];
$compacted_text=preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$decoded_text);   // remove extra spacing
$truncated_text=substr($compacted_text,0,100);       // cut the string to max length of 100
echo $truncated_text,'...';                          // print to screen and append with ...
```

Output:

```
If someone had said to me ten years ago that autism and the therapeutic benefits of gardening will b...
```