# How to get the contents within a td having a class?

Tags: html, regex

I want to get the contents of a `td` with a class and replace it with another content. I am not able to get the whole content within the `td` as it contains `linebreaks`.

I tried using `<td class="guest_invite"([^<]*)` and some other patterns. But none of theme are working

```
<table cellpadding="10" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;font-size:13px;margin-top:20px;font-family: opensans;">
    <tr>
        <td class="guest_invite" style="font-size:13px;border-right: 2px solid #CCC; vertical-align:top; padding:20px 20px 0px 0px; line-height:1.5; text-align:justify;" width="60%">Dear Guest,<br>
            I would like to personally thank you for choosing our Cruises. We can't wait for you to enjoy the experience of discovering many fascinating destinations in a single voyage.<br>
            You will fall in love with the gorgeous resort-style amenities.<br>
            Happy Cruising!
            <table style="margin-left:220px;padding-top:20px;font-family: opensans;width:auto;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div><img alt="Logo" src="/sites/default/files/2019-05/sign.png" style="height:85px;width:128px;margin-top:5px;">
                        <div style="font-size:10px;">Pierfrancesco Vago<br>
                        Executive Chairman MSC Cruises</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't feel content gets stripped because it has line breaks.  Also, why `PHP` tag?

Comment: It contains more than just line breaks. It contains a whole other table as well

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to get at this information

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation is achieved via JS (javascript) using jQuery (simpler), not PHP (which is used to render the HTML).

Here's a small snippet to get you started:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("td.guest_invite").html(/* put here whatever content you want to replace it with */);
});
</script>
```

Look [here](https://api.jquery.com/html/) for more information on jQuery `html` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Works in chrome console.
To get the content `document.querySelector(".guest_invite").textContent;` To update the content   `document.querySelector(".guest_invite").textContent = " your content";` OF course you must add the code inside `<script></script>` tags or in external js file. I would also suggest you use external stylesheets.

Comment: We have an api end point where the api call comes from a java application. The api call will provide a json based on which
we have to populate the data and generate a pdf. There are conditions based on which some text has to be changed in the pdf. 
But these text has to be taken from some tables.So what we do is, based on the conditions we put different tokens. That is why we use php to validate the conditions. So if I can get a regex in php to validate the same it would be useful

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602251/php-regex-find-text-between-custom-added-html-tags