# Get the values ​that are in the tags [img][/img] php

Tags: php

Please tell me how I can derive the values ​​`123.jpg` and `456.jpg` that are in the `[img][/img]` tags from this line:

```
$str = "Text 1 [img]123.jpg[/img] Text 2 [img]456.jpg[/img]";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Regex find text between custom added HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602251/php-regex-find-text-between-custom-added-html-tags)

Comment: @Laim Alas, no, because in my question a completely different structure.

Comment: @GameEagle still the same approach works, you just need a different regex

Comment: @GameEagle, actually yes, because your structure is absolutely the same - text between some tags (no matter the shape).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$re = '/\[img\](.*?\.jpg)\[\/img\]/m';
$str = 'Text 1 [img]123.jpg[/img] Text 2 [img]456.jpg[/img]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);


foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (isset($match[1])) {
        unlink($match[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use a function for each resulting value? Namely unlink.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Just to demonstrate the approach from the post, reported by @Laim:

```
<?php
    $str = "Text 1 [img]123.jpg[/img] Text 2 [img]456.jpg[/img]";
    preg_match_all('/\[img](.*?)\[\/img]/s', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123.jpg
    [1] => 456.jpg
)
```